# Mongodb compound shard key with tag aware sharding

Tags: mongodb

Mongodb compound shard key with tag aware sharding.

**Environment**

- I have a `mongodb` cluster with 4 shards.
- The first two shards have a country tag of `Americas` and the last two shards have a tag of `Europe`.
- The shard key is compound on the fields `country, user, domain`.

**Problem**

I'm trying to have tag aware sharding based on country, so any document with `country: 1` will be auto sharded between the first two shards and any document with `country: 2` will be auto sharded to the last 2 shards.

```
Sample Data:`
"_id" : ObjectId("56c4cc2fb086de4769800fe4"), "timestamp" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"), "user" : "guest", "category" : "Google", "domain" : "google.com", "source" : 1.1.1.1, "destination" : 2.2.2.2, "country" : 1, "__v" : 0`
"_id" : ObjectId("56c4cc2fb086de4769800fe4"), "timestamp" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"), "user" : "guest2", "category" : "Bing", "domain" : "bing.com", "source" : 2.2.2.2, "destination" : 3.3.3.3, "country" : 2, "__v" : 0`

config.tags:
"_id" : { "ns" : "logs.sitea", "min" : { "country" : "1" } }, "ns" : "logs.sitea", "min" : { "country" : "1" }, "max" : { "country" : "2" }, "tag" : "Americas"`
"_id" : { "ns" : "logs.siteb", "min" : { "country" : "2" } }, "ns" : "logs.siteb", "min" : { "country" : "2" }, "max" : { "country" : "3" }, "tag" : "Europe"`

config.shards:
"_id" : "shard0000", "host" : "1.1.1.1:27019", "tags" : [ "Americas" ]`
"_id" : "shard0001", "host" : "1.1.1.2:27019", "tags" : [ "Americas" ]`
"_id" : "shard0002", "host" : "2.2.2.2:27019", "tags" : [ "Europe" ]`
"_id" : "shard0003", "host" : "2.2.2.3:27019", "tags" : [ "Europe" ]`

sh.status:
"_id" : "logs",  "primary" : "shard0002",  "partitioned" : true`
            logs.sitea`
                    shard key: { "country" : 1, "user" : 1, "domain" : 1 }
                    unique: false`
                    balancing: true`
                    chunks:`
                    tag: Americas  { "country" : "1" } -->> { "country" : "2"`

"_id" : "logs",  "primary" : "shard0002",  "partitioned" : true }`
            logs.siteb`
                    shard key: { "country" : 1, "user" : 1, "domain" : 1 
                    unique: false`
                    balancing: true`
                    chunks:`
                    tag: Europe  { "country" : "2" } -->> { "country" : "3" }
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the double quotes around the country codes.

Updating the tag to this resolved my problem:
"_id" : { "ns" : "logs.sitea", "min" : { "country" : 1 } }, "ns" : "logs.sitea", "min" : { "country" : 1 }, "max" : { "country" : 2 }, "tag" : "Americas"`